# Algorithmic elimination based on roles of objects

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Five possible roles exists which only one person can be assigned to and needs to be proficient with.
The roles are **farmer, programmer, doctor, salesman and football player**. By elimination this should be the result/output with no footballplayer available.

What would be a clean solution to solve this "problem". Examples in java would be most helpful but pseudo code or hints are just as appreciated.

Input:

```
+--------+--------------------------------------+
| Person |                Roles                 |
+--------+--------------------------------------+
|      1 | Farmer                               |
|      2 | Programmer, Doctor, Farmer           |
|      3 | Programmer, Doctor                   |
|      4 | Salesman, Farmer, Doctor, Programmer |
+--------+--------------------------------------+
```

```
+--------+--------------------+
| Person |       Roles        |
+--------+--------------------+
|      1 | Farmer             |
|      2 | Programmer, Doctor |
|      3 | Programmer, Doctor |
|      4 | Salesman           |
+--------+--------------------+
```

Edit:

What I tried so far is two things but is definetly not flexible since there are a lot of possibilities:

1. If one persone only has one role he automaticaly gets the role. Problem here is that if there are more than one person who have the same role and it is their only role.
2. If two persons have two roles and have exactly the same roles they both get the roles assigned. Problem here is if more than 2 persons share all the same roles.

Comment: Did you try something so far? Please share it

Comment: Hello. StackOverflow is not a problem-solving site, we don't write code for you. If you have a specific question about your current attempt at solution for this problem, then show us *that code*, and explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your example?

Comment: In response to after-edit changes: you have difficulties because your algorithm doesn't define how to handle collisions. This is basically a dining philosopher problem, with jobs instead of spoons. As such, there must be some kind of policy for collision resolution.

Comment: This descriptions looks very incomplete (and the problem looks like homework). The problem is easily tackled by SAT-solving or Constraint-programming techniques. The transitions from table 1 to table 2 is exactly what SAT-based [unit-propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_propagation) would do on some formulation of the assignment-constraint (row- and col-sums = 1; see linear assignment problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nice example of [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) (Constraint satisfaction problem) or [COP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_optimization) (Constraint optimization problems) in case you can't (or don't need to) have a perfect result.

I won't write a source code for you, but here is the basic outline of what you need to do:

Recursively try all possible combinations, with pruning and ordering. What it essentially means is:

In each level of recursion:

1. Sort your entries by number of remaining assignable jobs
2. For the one with the least number of jobs, pick one to keep and remove it from all others.
3. Repeat these steps for this assignment
4. If you find inconsistency (e.g. no more jobs left for a person) backtrack (go back in the recursive tree to the moment before the critical assignment was made) and try different assignment from remaining available ones. If there is no possible different assignment which would not result in inconsistency, backtrack more
5. Once all of the people have assigned roles, you can exit. If you get to the top of the tree from backtracking, it means there is no solution.

All of this above assumes you have enough roles for all people (e.g. Every person can do at least one thing, and the thing is not the same as everyone else's only thing). With some modification, you can relax this condition a little (depends on the exact definition of your problem)

This algorithm can result in multiple solutions. From your example of:

```
|      2 | Programmer, Doctor |
|      3 | Programmer, Doctor |
```

There are (at least) 2 valid results. `Person #1` will be a `Programmer` and `#3` a `Doctor` or vice versa

There are a lot more tricks to speed this up. For example, you can assign roles to people in the most constraining order, which means the ones that will block the most other people first. Or in between each step do a [arc-consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_consistency#Arc_consistency) check, such as [AC-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC-3_algorithm)